# Catkin install destination

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin, path, environment, environment-variables

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to figure out where my files should be installed by the Cmake install() macro (ROS melodic on Ubuntu 18.04). I found this [list of catkin environment variables](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/user_guide/variables.html) which are relative to the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. But how can I actually find the path of the install destinations to check if my files were successfully installed? I tried `echo $CATKIN_GLOBAL_INCLUDE_DESTINATION` or `echo $CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` which both output an empty line.

I'm also wondering why I never had an install folder in my workspace yet. Should I change my `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` path when using ROS? I never read anything about this before. Some packages are even missing the install macro completely and work fine anyway.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342050/catkin-install-destination/) by [prex](https://answers.ros.org/users/35086/prex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2020-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2020-01-19**:
Running `catkin_make install` should create an `install` folder in your workspace. If our packages contain install directives.

A good explanation can be found here:
https://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace#Installing_Packages

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-19**:
For which variables you should use, and how, you'll want to take a look at the [catkin 0.7.20 documentation » How to do common tasks » Package format 2 (recommended)](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html). Specifically the *Building and installing targets* section.

There are conventions for where files should end up and they are documented in those articles.

**Comment by [prex](https://answers.ros.org/users/35086/prex/) on 2020-01-19**:
Do I also need to source the install space?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-01-21**:\

> Do I also need to source the install space?

Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I realized that I needed to set `catkin config --install` for the catkin_tools first, so that the install folder is created (already with the correct prefix path). Together with the two links above, this explains why I never found these files.

But packages also run fine from the devel space. In this case they can for example [include header files from source space](https://answers.ros.org/question/150306/how-to-put-headers-into-develinclude-folder-with-catkin_make/), which confused me a little bit at the beginning, because they were not present in devel.

I am still happy to hear how to check the path of these environment variables.

---

Originally posted by [prex](https://answers.ros.org/users/35086/prex/) with karma: 151 on 2020-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-01-21**:
The variables you mentioned (e.g. `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`) are CMake variables - not environment variables in your shell. They are simply not available after the build has finished. The install prefix is by default the `install` subdirectory of your workspace.